# Nativescript : Android new navigation bar

Tags: nativescript

According to Google's new Material Design [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html), the navigation bar is supposed to be at the bottom. How can I implement it (if there is a way) ? For the moment, I'm using a Tabview which, by default on Android, is put at the top of the page. 
Thank you

Comment: It's not "supposed to be there". It's just an option, now that they pulled a 180 on that particular design guideline.

Comment: Sorry bad choice of words

Comment: Have you tried the [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) available in the design support library.

Comment: Actually I'm not coding my Android app with Java but with [Nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/about) so I don't have access to all the Android components

Comment: @Dat Nguyen - Yes you do have access - one way is to use placeholder in which you can load native components (both Android and iOS) [https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder.html](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder.html)

Comment: @NickIliev thanks I'll check that

Answer (score 4):

As of right now there isn't a shipped widget from Google. So you have to roll your own. There are several open source implementations of the component spec.

One of the better ones I have found that you could use with NativeScript is, https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Another alternative is to use a `grid-layout` pinned to the bottom of you view, set the navigation bar to be transparent, this is covered in my blog post [here](https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/). Then you could use the nativescript animation API to animate the labels for the effect. You would then use this  :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html#createCircularReveal(android.view.View, int, int, float, float) to animate the circular reveal effect.

I might write up a post using already available NativeScript and then if I have time make that library into a plugin for [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)

I put this together in a few minutes yesterday using a library for the Bottom Bar. [image]

Answer (score 4):

For this case, i created a custom Nativescript component. It's really basic but i hope it will help you.

- app/components/bottom-navigation.ts

```js
import gridLayoutModule = require("ui/layouts/grid-layout");
import {Label} from "ui/label";
import dependencyObservableModule = require("ui/core/dependency-observable");
import {EventData} from "data/observable";
import frameModule = require("ui/frame");

export class BottomNavigation extends gridLayoutModule.GridLayout {
    public static selectedItemProperty = new dependencyObservableModule.Property(
        "selectedItem",
        "BottomNavigation",
        new dependencyObservableModule.PropertyMetadata(undefined, dependencyObservableModule.PropertyMetadataSettings.None,
        function(data: dependencyObservableModule.PropertyChangeData) {
            if (data.newValue) {
                let instance = <BottomNavigation>data.object;
                instance.setSelectedItem(data.newValue);
            }
        }));

    public get selectedItem() {
        return this._getValue(BottomNavigation.selectedItemProperty);
    }
    public set selectedItem(value: string) {
        this._setValue(BottomNavigation.selectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    private _items = [
        { code: "TAB_1", icon: 0xe90a, label: "Tab 1" },
        { code: "TAB_2", icon: 0xe90b, label: "Tab 2"},
        { code: "TAB_3", icon: 0xe90c, label: "Tab 3"}];

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.createUi();
    }

    public setSelectedItem(selectedItem: string) {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;

        let icon = this.getViewById(selectedItem + "_ICON");
        icon.className = icon.className.replace("icon-unselected", "icon-selected");

        let label = this.getViewById(selectedItem + "_LABEL");
        label.className = "label-selected";
    }

    private createUi() {
        this.removeChildren();

        this.className = "bottom-navigation";

        this.addColumn(new gridLayoutModule.ItemSpec(1, "star"));
        this.addColumn(new gridLayoutModule.ItemSpec(1, "star"));
        this.addColumn(new gridLayoutModule.ItemSpec(1, "star"));

        for (let i = 0; i < this._items.length; i++) {
            let currentItem = this._items[i];

            let icon = new Label();
            icon.id = currentItem.code + "_ICON";
            icon.text = String.fromCharCode(currentItem.icon);
            icon.className = "material-icon icon-unselected";
            icon.on("tap", args => this.onNavigate(args, currentItem.code));
            this.addChild(icon);
            gridLayoutModule.GridLayout.setColumn(icon, i);

            let label = new Label();
            label.id = currentItem.code + "_LABEL";
            label.text = currentItem.label;
            label.className = "label-unselected";
            label.on("tap", args => this.onNavigate(args, currentItem.code));
            this.addChild(label);
            gridLayoutModule.GridLayout.setColumn(label, i);
        }
    }

    private onNavigate(args: EventData, code: string) {
        let selectedLabel = <Label>args.object;

        if (selectedLabel.className.indexOf("icon-selected") > -1) {
            return;
        }

        let destinationUrl = "";

        switch (code) {
            case "TAB_1":
                destinationUrl = "views/tab-1/tab-1";
                break;
            case "TAB_2":
                destinationUrl = "views/tab-2/tab-2";
                break;
            case "TAB_3":
                destinationUrl = "views/tab-3/tab-3";
                break;
        }

        frameModule.topmost().navigate({
            animated: false,
            backstackVisible: false,
            moduleName: destinationUrl
        });
    }
}
```

- my-view.xml

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    xmlns:bn="components/bottom-navigation">
  <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
    <GridLayout>
      <!-- Your view here -->
    </GridLayout>
    <bn:BottomNavigation row="1" selectedItem="TAB_1" />
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

EDIT : Here is the associated SASS style

```
.bottom-navigation {
    background-color: $primary-color;
    height: 56;
    color: $primary-color-text;

    .icon {
        horizontal-align: center;
        font-size:46;
    }

    .icon-selected {
        @extend .icon;
    }

    .icon-unselected {
        @extend .icon;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    .label {
        horizontal-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        margin-bottom: 4;
    }

    .label-unselected {
        @extend .label;
        visibility: collapse;
    }

    .label-selected {
        @extend .label;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check this

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect solution but,
Since you should use viewpager in this case. Put gravity of the parent linear layout to bottom. The tab automatically moves to bottom of the page.

Hope this helps thanks!!!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the solution you gave me is used when you code your Android app with Java but that's not the case for me